# Opening a second vs2012 window asks for admin privileges and to save solution?

Tags: windows, visual-studio, visual-studio-2012, windows-8.1

I have Visual Studio 2012 Ultimate installed on my machine and I use it daily for work. I also have VS 2013 professional installed but rarely use it.  I am running windows 8.1.

Recently, when I have one VS2012 window open and I middle click on the VS entry in the windows task bar to open a new window, the window opens but it doesn't go to the start page like my first window does when it opens.

First, I get this message:
[image]

If I then attempt to open a solution from the File menu, it asks me if I want to save the changes to devenv.sln.

I'm not sure why it started doing this, but it has only been happening for the past few weeks (or maybe a month or two).

I've searched for solutions but the [only discussion I found is other post](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/8716b5e9-0565-459e-8970-93db52cab466/save-changes-to-devenvsln).  I changed vslauncher.exe to run with admin privileges like the post says, but this didn't help.

How can I get the second VS2012 window to just open the start page when it starts?